# Express/Node.JS middleware raising error, keeps processing

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, express

I'm beginning under NodeJS/Express and I'm facing the following problem (I probably didn't get all the tricks of async programming yet)

I've made a middleware in charge of checking if a oauth_token paramters is passed (actually implementing oAuth layer on my node server)

I'm doing this :

```
function myMiddle(req,res,next) {
  var oAuthToken = req.query["oauth_token"];
  if (oAuthToken == undefined) {
            res.send(406);
            res.end();
    next(new Error('No token provided'));   
}
/* Basically doing some DB stuff with MongoDB, connecting and using oAuthToken provided to query, etc.. */
```

The thing is that I expected the code to "die" when he doesn't receive the oauth_token parameters in the query string. It's actually raising me an error and returning greatly 406 error to my HTTP client, but code keeps processing behind and raises me mutable headers errors caused by my processing code after, and my script dies.

Something I'm missing? Thanks by advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `oAuthToken` is undefined Node.js makes a response. After that you fire `next(...)` which tries to make another response to the same request. This fails and you see what you see.  Note that in Node.js using `res.send();` and `res.end();` does not stop your function. So what you need is to do the following:

```
function myMiddle(req,res,next) {
  var oAuthToken = req.query["oauth_token"];
  if (oAuthToken == undefined) {
    next(new Error('No token provided')); // handle everything here

    // res.send(406);
    // res.end();
    // unnecessary, throws errors because you try to respond twice
  }
  // do something if this is fine
}
```

or do it the other way - use `res.send(406); res.end();` without `next(...)`.

Comment: I tried that aswell and the code kept processing again. Like I said in the comment below I fixed it by returning next('error') instead of just invoking it. Does it seems logic to you?

Comment: It does not. :D Well actually it does, it only means that you force the function to stop workin after `next()` is called. Maybe you should modify a bit my code and use `if {...} else {...}`? It is important that nothing (what has something to do with response) runs after `next()`. That's all I can say, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

This might be late, but I just encountered this issue as well. You can actually pass the error to ErrorHandler so that the middleware would not continue to the next middleware or router while you can send the HTTP status code you want.

**Your middleware**

```
function myMiddle(req, res, next) {
  // Do validate your OAuth token
  // you might want to do better validation of the token here
  // instead of just checking its existence
  //
  // var oAuthToken = req.query['oauth_token'];
  //
  // According to JSLint, you can just directly select the object as:
  //
  // req.query.oauth_token

  if (req.query.oauth_token === undefined) {

    // Just let the ErrorHandler does the rest
    // like redirecting or just send message to client
    var err = new Error('Unauthorized access.');
    err.status(406); // Or 403, or any HTTP status code

    // Pass it to ErrorHandler
    next(err);

  } else {
    // Do something here, or just
    next();
  }
}
```

**Your ErrorHandler**

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
  if (err.status == 406) {
    // You can just do res.sendStatus()
    res.sendStatus(406); // Set HTTP status code as 406 and send message to client

    // Or chaining res.status() with res.send()
    res.status(406).res.send(); // or res.render(), or res.json()

    return;

  }

  // Others
});
```

More about ErrorHandler: http://expressjs.com/ja/guide/error-handling.html

Answer (score 0):

Do you have express error handling (`app.use(express.errorHandler())` in your middleware stack?

Also see the [Express middleware section](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#middleware) for details on how to use `next()`.

Comment: Yeah, I have the error handler. Actually I "solved" (not sure if it's clean or not) by returning next('error') instead of just calling next. I guess it makes senses, as it makes the functions exiting